# counting occurence of character

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
chr1A_p1
chr1A_p2
chr10B_p1
chr10A_p1
chr11D_p2
chr18B_p2
chr9D_p1
```

I need to count number of time A, B & D occur. Individually, I would do it like this

```
awk '{if($1~/A/) print $0 }' < test.txt | wc
awk '{if($1~/B/) print $0 }' < test.txt | wc
awk '{if($1~/D/) print $0 }' < test.txt | wc
```

How to join these lines so that I can count number of A,B,D just through one liner instead of 3 separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specific line format (where the needed char is before `_`):

```
$ awk -F"_" '{ seen[substr($1, length($1))]++ }END{ for(k in seen) print k, seen[k] }' file
A 3
B 2
D 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Counting occurrences is generally done by keeping track of a counter. So a single of the OP's awk lines;

```
awk '{if($1~/A/) print $0}' < test.txt | wc
```

can be rewritten as

```
awk '($1~/A/){c++}END{print c}' test.txt
```

for multiple cases, you can now do:

```
awk '($1~/A/){c["A"]++}
     ($1~/B/){c["B"]++}
     ($1~/D/){c["D"]++}
     END{for(i in c) print i,c[i]}' test.txt
```

Now you can even clean this up a bit more:

```
awk '{c["A"]+=($1~/A/)}
     {c["B"]+=($1~/B/)}
     {c["D"]+=($1~/D/)}
     END{for(i in c) print i,c[i]}' test.txt
```

which you can clean up further as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("A B D",a)}
     {for(i in a) c[a[i]]+=($1~a[i])}
     END{for(i in c) print i,c[i]}' test.txt
```

But these cases just count how many times a line occurs that contains the letter, not how many times the letter occurs.

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("A B D",a)}
     {for(i in a) c[a[i]]+=gsub(a[i],"",$1)}
     END{for(i in c) print i,c[i]}' test.txt
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last "c" be "c[i]"?

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne '$seen{$1}++ if /([ABD])/; END { print "$_:$seen{$_}" for keys %seen }' < test.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- a hash table `%seen` is used to keep the number of occurrences of each symbol. Each time it's matched it's captured and the corresponding field in the hash is incremented.
- `END` is run when the file ends. It outputs all the keys of the hash, i.e. the matched characters, each followed by the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

datafile:

```
chr1A_p1
chr1A_p2
chr10B_p1
chr10A_p1
chr11D_p2
chr18B_p2
chr9D_p1
```

script.awk

```
BEGIN {
    arr["A"]=0
    arr["B"]=0
    arr["D"]=0
} 
/A/ { arr["A"]++ }
/B/ { arr["B"]++ } 
/D/ { arr["D"]++ }  
END {
    printf "A: %s, B: %s, D: %s", arr["A"], arr["B"], arr["D"]
}
```

execution:

```
 awk -f script.awk datafile
```

result:

```
A: 3, B: 2, D: 2
```

Comment: Your `BEGIN` clause isn't necessary.

Comment: I agree. It is also not an obstacle. Sometimes it's better to sacrifice brevity for clarity and not rely on default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` one liner come to `perl`'s rescue :

```
perl -lne '$seen{$1}++ if /([ABD])/; END { print "$_:$seen{$_}" for keys %seen }'
```

> 

```
awk '{ __[$2]++ } END { for(_ in __) print _, __[_] }' FS='[^A-Z]*'
```

---

```
A 3
B 2
D 2
```